# How get the value of element $item["@attributes"]["tag"]

Tags: php, arrays, simplexml

How can I call to $item["@attributes"]["tag"]?
I receive the Fatal error: Cannot use string offset as an array in line:

```
if ($item["@attributes"]["tag"] == $field)
```

**My steps: I receiving XML string, extract it to SimpleXMLObject:**

```
object(SimpleXMLElement)#6 (1) 
{ 
["rec"]=> object(SimpleXMLElement)#7 (1) 
  { 
    ["datafield"]=> array(1) { 
    [0]=> object(SimpleXMLElement)#10 (3) 
       {
        ["@attributes"]=> array(1) { 
        ["tag"]=> string(2) "99" 
        }   
        ["@attributes"]=> array(1) { 
        ["tag"]=> string(3) "100" 
        } 

        ["subfield"]=> array(3) { 
         [0]=> string(5) "text0" 
         [1]=> string(5) "text1" 
         [2]=> string(4) "test" 
        } 
       } 
       } 
  } 
}
```

Because I have no attribute [code] in SimpleXMLObject I convert it to array, to find the [tag]="100" and change ["code"] or if code=z not exist create it and insert value that I should change or create:

```
array(1) {
  ["hold"]=> array(1) { 
     ["rec"]=> array(1){ 
      ["datafield"]=> array(2) { 
      [0]=> array(2) 
         { 
          ["subfield"]=> array(1) { 
           [0]=> array(2) { 
              ["@value"]=> string(4) "test" 
              ["@attributes"]=> array(1){ 
              ["code"]=> string(1) "z" 
              } 
             } 
         } 
           ["@attributes"]=> array(1) { 
             ["tag"]=> string(3) "100" 
            } 
          } 
        } 
     } 
 } 
}
```

**This is my PHP code to access the array:**

```
foreach ($xml_ray['hold']['rec'] as $key_item => $item) {
   if ($item["@attributes"]["tag"] == $field) { // Line where I get the ERROR
      foreach ($item['subfield'] as $key_subfield => $subfield) {
          $code = $subfield['@attributes']['code'];
          $value = $subfield['@value'];
               //  ....       
     if ($checksum==2 && $code==$subfield_file) {
           $checksum++;
          }

        if ($checksum == 3) { $xml_hold_ray['hold']['rec'][$key_item]['subfield'][$key_subfield]['@value'] = $new_code;
          }
            }

         }
      }
```

The Origin XML:

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
    <hold>
    <rec>
      <datafield ind1=" " ind2=" " tag="99">
       <subfield code="a">text</subfield>
      </datafield>
      <datafield ind1="1" ind2=" " tag="100">
        <subfield code="b">text0</subfield>
        <subfield code="c">text1</subfield>
        <subfield code="z">test2</subfield>
      </datafield>
    </rec>
    </hold>
```

**The whole code for Understand the work of it:**

```
 foreach ($xml_ray['hold']['rec'] as $key_item => $item) {

      if ($item["@attributes"]["tag"] == $field) {
  $info_msg = "FIELD: $field <br />";
    $outcame_msg .="Found correct field $field<br />";
  foreach ($item['subfield'] as $key_subfield => $subfield) {
      $code = $subfield['@attributes']['code'];
    $value = $subfield['@value'];
      $info_holding_msg.="$code = $value<br />";

      if ($value==$li) {
    $outcame_msg .= "Found correct li in subfield $code<br />";
    $checksum++;
    }
      if ($value==$loc) {
    $outcame_msg .= "Found correct loc in subfield $code<br />";
    $checksum++;
    }

       if ($checksum==2 && $code==$subfield_file) {

       $outcame_msg .= "Found subfield $code with value: $value<br />";
       $checksum++;
      }

    if ($checksum == 3) {

    $xml_ray['hold']['rec'][$key_item]['subfield'][$key_subfield]['@value'] = $new_code;
    $outcame_msg.="data found, changing data accepted.";
      }           
        }         
     }
   }
```

**Update new XML:**

```
$data ='<holds total="4">
<hold link="#">
<hold_id>0000000000000000</hold_id>
<lib desc="Lib">text</lib>
<loc desc="Lib2">text1</loc>
<sup>false</sup>
</hold>
<hold link="#">
<hold_id>0000000000000000</hold_id>
<lib desc="Lib">text</lib>
<loc desc="Lib2">text1</loc>
<sup>false</sup>
</hold>
<hold link="#">
<hold_id>0000000000000000</hold_id>
<lib desc="Lib">text3</lib>
<loc desc="Lib2">text4</loc>
<sup>false</sup>
</hold>   
</holds>';
```

Comment: Instead `$item["@attributes"]["tag"]` try to use `$item["@attributes"]->tag()`

Comment: in second line `$item` is the 'datafield' array. you need to go one level down.  `$item[0]["@attributes"]["tag"]`

Comment: It may be possible to sort this problem using SimpleXML if you post your original XML

Comment: You shouldn't ever need to convert a SimpleXML object to an array to retrieve/manipulate any of it - attributes are accessed via array syntax, e.g. `(string) $element['attribute']`, you should never be referring to the `@attributes` key directly.

Comment: I can't because I can't see in XML the attribute [TAG], the original XML obtained like a string. @Iainn how can I do it?

Comment: Can you post the original string you get, the conversion to an array doesn't invent tags or attributes, so it must be in there.

Comment: @Nigel Ren Should do Var_dump?

Comment: You can just do an echo, if this is to a browser though, you may need to do a view source to get the original content rather than what the browser displays.

Comment: @J. Litvak I tried Your option receiving error:  Call to a member function tag() on a non-object

Comment: @Jeff I tried Your version receiving an Error: Cannot use string offset as an array

Comment: @NigelRen I edited the question and added the Full XML

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using SimpleXML, this is how to access the data

```
$data = <<< XML
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?> 
<hold> 
<rec>
  <datafield ind1=" " ind2=" " tag="99">
   <subfield code="a">text</subfield>
  </datafield>
  <datafield ind1="1" ind2=" " tag="100">
    <subfield code="b">text0</subfield>
    <subfield code="c">text1</subfield>
    <subfield code="z">test2</subfield>
  </datafield>
</rec>
</hold>
XML;

$xml_ray = simplexml_load_string($data);

// A test value
$field = "100";
$checksum=2;
$new_code = 't1';
$subfield_file="z";

// Loop through all the <datafield> elements
foreach ( $xml_ray->rec->datafield as $item ) {
    if ( $item['tag'] == $field )    {
        $replaced = false;
        foreach ($item->subfield as $subfield) {
            if ($subfield['code']==$subfield_file) {
                $subfield[0] = $new_code;
                $replaced = true;
            }
        }
        if ( $replaced == false )   {
            $newItem = $item->addChild("subfield", $new_code);
            $newItem->addAttribute("code", $subfield_file);
        }
    }
}
```

See the way you use `->rec` to access the sub elements and `['tag']` to access the attributes.

I'm not 100% sure about what your doing with the middle bit of code, but I've tried to add in what I think your doing.  This code doesn't add it in if it doesn't exist and I'm not sure how the `$checksum` field processing works.

Two examples of how to use XPath...

```
$match = $xml_ray->xpath("//datafield[subfield[@code='z']]");
if ( count($match) > 0 )    {
    echo "Found match";
}
else    {
    echo "No match found";
}
$match = $xml_ray->xpath("//datafield[@tag='100'][subfield[@code='z1']]");
if ( count($match) > 0 )    {
    echo "Found match";
}
else    {
    echo "No match found";
}
```

The first (`//datafield[subfield[@code='z']]`) matches any datafield element with a subfield which has an attrbute code with a value of 'z'. This finds an element so prints 'Found Match'.

The second (`//datafield[@tag='100'][subfield[@code='z1']]` ) matches any datafield element which has a tag attribute = 100 and a subfield with code = 'z1'. This doesn't find an element so prints 'No match found'.

Update:
If you want to select the value of the datafield element with attribute tag = 100 and sibfield with code="z", then...

```
$match = $xml_ray->xpath("//datafield[@tag='100']/subfield[@code='z']");
echo (string)$match[0];
```

I've changed the XPath slightly from before, but this XPath gives...

```
test2
```

Comment: can I replace the value of the code=z? or create it if it is not exist?

Comment: Code added is more a translation of what you already had as not all sure how it works.

Comment: I tried this: foreach ( $xml_ray->rec as $item ) {
echo  $item->datafield['tag'];    
}  and receiving just first tag and it is more. What will be the bug?

Comment: Your XML only contains 1 datafield element.

Comment: Edited, I wanted do it short, but now fill it more information.

Comment: OK - it's because the repeated item is `<datafield>` so I've moved this to the first `foreach` loop - `foreach ( $xml_ray->rec->datafield as $item ) {` and then removed the reference to it in the following lines.

Comment: It is do it, but how can I edit field with code "z"? and place it back to XML? Or more Important question Can I create the code="z" if it not exist?

Comment: I've changed the middle section to check each `<subfield>` for the one indicated by `$subfield_file` and update it if it's there with `$new_code`, if the value isn't replaced the following `if` creates a new element.

Comment: How Can I save it into my XML? $xml_ray->rec->$subfield[0]? I tried to print my xml and it was not changed. In my code I used -  $xml_ray['hold']['rec'][$key_item]['subfield'][$key_subfield]['@value'] = $new_code; to insert it to whole XML.

Comment: why do You replace $subfield[0] - 0?

Comment: `$subfield[0] = $new_code;` sets the value in the original XML, you have to use `[0]` to make PHP set the value of the element and not just replace the field.

Comment: Yes but how can I get all XML with replaced value? I tried to echo it, but nothing. Also should I load it back from string to XML?

Comment: `echo $xml_ray->asXML();` will give the full XML.

Comment: the variable $xml_ray->asXML(); I can send the whole XML code? is it right? I should insert it back to system. can I do any check for XML if exist few same <hold></hold> - records (more than one) with same subfields "a" and "b", in this case not update else just print an error massage?

Comment: If you want to see if there are other records with that subfield and code combination, then look into how to use XPath and use something like... `//datafield[subfield[@code="z"]]`  this will return any matching records anywhere in the document

Comment: I need any example if You have,  please, I should datafield[subfield[@code="z"]] and if exist in my Xml file any record with subfieĺd -> code a='htdc' and subfiend ->code b = 'clsd' for example, I mean that I compare not for code else for code value(a='value' &b='value'). Can I do it? And in this case not replace or create code Z else just alert an error.

Comment: I've added some new code, but this probably should have been a new question as this one has been going on for days.

Comment: I checked in online runphponline code, and it add "z" if it not exist, why do You say it is not add? If I will ask new question, I will should explain all once more, it is take few days, because there are code what I should check before I can tell if it is work and help to solve the problem and answer to my question, I doing the sample thing, I receiving XML, find datafield with tag="100", and subfield with code = b value=text0 
and subfield with code="c" value= text1, after that if exist subfield with code=z I replace value of it, else create subfield with code z and new value.

Comment: just think about if exist more than one hold records with same fields with tag=100, and subfields with codes b=text0,c=text1, I should in this case alert error masage. after all my procedure steps I should receive the XML with changes if it needed. Why You told me that the code "z" not creating if not exist? As I tried it is. And first of all I thank You a lot, for Your help to answers my question and help at all. It is very important for me. The check of the exist same hold records fields and subilds just should tell me if I should go over to insert the changes or exit and do nothing

Comment: 'Why You told me that the code "z" not creating if not exist?' In a comment 2 days ago I said I had changed the code and 'if the value isn't replaced the following if creates a new element'

Comment: because I read these: I'm not 100% sure about what your doing with the middle bit of code, but I've tried to add in what I think your doing. This code doesn't add it in if it doesn't exist and I'm not sure how the $checksum field processing works.

Comment: It is working, just the one step I can't over still, I receiving the XML like sample XML, and convert in to: $xml_ray = simplexml_load_string($data); but after that I should send it back by URL+API, and I do  $hold_updated_xml=$xml_ray->asXML(); and or I receive the GENERAL_ERROR A Gateway error has occurred: XML is not well-formed how can I convert it back to send it via URL with API?

Comment: I tested if I put the received XML and send it back it is working, just after my manipulations: $xml_ray = simplexml_load_string($data); and $hold_updated_xml=$xml_ray->asXML(); I receive the  A Gateway error has occurred: XML is not well-formed. how can I solve it?

Comment: This is another question altogether, this question is 'How get the value of element $item[“@attributes”][“tag”]'.  Post a new question with the code you have so far, the XML it's generating and the error your getting.  You will get more help as I won't be the only person who is reading your messages.

Comment: NigelRen, I solved this, the problem was that added to my XML the: $header="<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' standalone='yes'?>"; I removed it via sending it with API url and it is working.

Comment: I checked the solution with green "V".

Comment: I just ask You one answer me please, about the xpath, if I want compare if exist more than one subfield with code=b value = GN and code c with value = ph   is it right sintax:   $match = $xml_ray->xpath("//datafield[@tag='100'][subfield[@code='b'].$subfield[0]]");
if ( count($match) > 0 )    { // Is it right? I need compare the subfield code value. I do like You told me before just the issue how I call to subfield code value in xpath case.

Comment: Nigel Ren, please answer to me, I tested now the whole my code, and the process change or create the "z" file just in case if subfield code = 100, but I should check if the subfield code = 100 and subfield b= text0 and subfield c = text1 . I mean:  <datafield ind1="1" ind2=" " tag="100">
    <subfield code="b">text0</subfield>
    <subfield code="c">text1</subfield>
  </datafield> This is my GOAL from start of the question how get the value of the subfield, can You answer or help with it? Please. It is still the open same question.

Comment: Hi NigelRen I solved all questions. But if You can please answer me one point or give me link to the material please. In the case $match = $xml_ray->xpath("//datafield[@tag='100'][subfield[@code='z']]"); How can I call to the value of the [subfield[@code='z']]?  <subfield code="z">test2</subfield> -> call to "test2"?

Comment: And If I can do it?

Comment: I've added the last piece of code for this question.

Comment: Thank You, but I find another way, see please(Example Updated XML): $match = $xml_ray->xpath("//hold[lib='text' and loc='text1']"); this way for few criterion it is working correct, but I can't echo the result to see it may be because the "and"?

Comment: Tell me please how can I output $match in my case? Simple the solution You tel is good, but in case with 2 criterion it is not working, so I tried another

Comment: It is my last question for this issue, please I need right call to this structure -
 see Update new XML: and can;t echo this in my case

Comment: Can You answer please?